# Why won't lxml strip section tags?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to parse some HTML with lxml and Python. I want to remove section tags. lxml seems to be capable of removing all other tags I specify but not section tags.

e.g.

```
test_html = '<section> <header> Test header </header> <p> Test text </p> </section>'
to_parse_html = etree.fromstring(test_html)

etree.strip_tags(to_parse_html,'header')
etree.tostring(to_parse_html)

'<section>  Test header  <p> Test text </p> </section>'

etree.strip_tags(to_parse_html,'p')
etree.tostring(to_parse_html)
'<section>  Test header   Test text  </section>'

etree.strip_tags(to_parse_html,'section')
etree.tostring(to_parse_html)
'<section>  Test header   Test text  </section>'
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Perhaps it isn't because of the `<section>` tag, but because `<section>` is the top level tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this the case?

It isn't. The [documention](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags) says the following:

> Note that this will not delete the element (or ElementTree root
>   element) that you passed even if it matches. It will only treat its
>   descendants.

So:

```
>>> tree = etree.fromstring('<section> outer <section> inner </section> </section>')
>>> etree.strip_tags(tree, 'section')
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<section> outer  inner  </section>'
```

The behavior that you see has nothing to do with the `<section>` tag, but with the fact that it happens to be the outermost tag of your snippet. The actual answer to your question is thus "because it's implemented that way".

To remove the outermost tag: is it possible to change the code that creates the `<section>...</section>` to do this? If not, an [`ElementDepthFirstIterator`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.ElementDepthFirstIterator-class.html) might do the trick:

```
>>> tree = etree.fromstring('<section> outer <section> inner </section> </section>')
>>> for val in etree.ElementDepthFirstIterator(tree, tag=None, inclusive=False):
...  print(etree.tostring(val))

b'<section> inner </section> '
```

Comment: I see, how would I go about removing the outermost tag then?

Comment: Depending on your goal, http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.ElementDepthFirstIterator-class.html with `inclusive=False` might work.